How can I @export a mapping of enum to Texture2D?
I have an enum and I want to assign a texture to each enum value. I can create an @export for each item in the enum, but that's clumsy. I can @export an array, but I can't tell which enum each entry represents. It doesn't seem like the enum markup in the docs will help and I don't see how I could use @export_custom.
Here's what I can currently achieve (Godot 4.3):
extends Resource

enum Payload {
    IRON,
    MERCURY,
    SULPHUR,
}

# List out each enum value:
@export var iron_tex: Texture2D
@export var mercury_tex: Texture2D
@export var sulphur_tex: Texture2D

func get_texure(payload: Payload):
    match payload:
        Payload.IRON:
            return iron_tex
        Payload.MERCURY:
            return mercury_tex
        Payload.SULPHUR:
            return sulphur_tex


## Maps Payload to textures (0 is IRON, ...)
@export var tex: Array[Texture2D]

func get_texure2(payload: Payload):
    if payload < tex.size():
        return tex[payload]

...


I'd hope for something more like:
@export_enum(Payload) var tex : Array[Texture2D]



I want to begin by mentioning that Godot 4.4 will have typed dictionaries. And I intend to use them to replace my solution once it is stable.
Suport for enum as key is not yet merged at time of writing (see #100512). Yet, I believe this feature would be just what you want.

You can iterate over the values of the enum (Since you have a named enum, you can access it as dictionary) and output the properties in _get_property_list, and handle them in _get and _set.
This is working code (tested in Godot 4.3):
@tool
extends Node

enum Payload {
    IRON,
    MERCURY,
    SULPHUR,
}

@export_storage var textures:Array[Texture2D] = []

func _get_property_list() -> Array[Dictionary]:
    var result:Array[Dictionary] = []
    result.append(
        {
            name = "Tex",
            type = TYPE_NIL,
            hint_string = "tex_",
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_GROUP
        }
    )
    for key:String in Payload:
        result.append(
            {
                name = "tex_" + key,
                type = TYPE_OBJECT, 
                hint = PROPERTY_HINT_RESOURCE_TYPE,
                hint_string = "Texture2D",
                usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_EDITOR
            }
        )

    return result

func _get(property:StringName) -> Variant:
    if not property.begins_with("tex_"):
        return null

    property = property.trim_prefix("tex_")
    if not Payload.has(property):
        return null

    if textures.size() != Payload.size():
        textures.resize(Payload.size())

    var enum_value:int = Payload[property]
    return textures[enum_value]

func _set(property:StringName, value:Variant) -> bool:
    if not property.begins_with("tex_"):
        return false

    property = property.trim_prefix("tex_")
    if not Payload.has(property):
        return false

    if textures.size() != Payload.size():
        textures.resize(Payload.size())

    var enum_value:int = Payload[property]
    textures[enum_value] = value
    return true


Another option is to have for the inspector a propery which type is the enum, and a property which type is a texture, and then using getter and setter, we map to the actual values.
This is working code (tested in Godot 4.3):
@tool
extends Node

enum Payload {
    IRON,
    MERCURY,
    SULPHUR,
}

@export_storage var textures:Array[Texture2D] = []

@export var current:Payload

@export var texture:Texture2D:
    get:
        if textures.size() != Payload.size():
            textures.resize(Payload.size())

        return textures[current]
    set(mod_value):
        if textures.size() != Payload.size():
            textures.resize(Payload.size())

        textures[current] = mod_value

func _validate_property(property: Dictionary) -> void:
    match property.name:
        "current", "texture":
            property.usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_EDITOR


Notes

With either of these code snippets adding new enum values does not imply extra effort, since this generates the properties based on the values of the enum.
Both code snippets check the size of the array on every access, which is not much trouble, but an alternative is to set the size of the array in _init.
Both code snippets assume the enum has consecutive integer keys (which is the default). If it is not the case, you could move from an array to a dictionary to hold the textures.
In both code snippets I'm using @export_storage so Godot stores the underlying property. And PROPERTY_USAGE_EDITOR is used to tell Godot to show a property in the inspector but not store it.


And finally, I want to mention that yet another option is to implement a custom property inspector. However, I don't think it is worth the effort for this case.
